# how can I get the segments off the uri

Tags: php, url, rest

My question and the thing that goes wrong

is when I have two segments

example: www.xxx.nl/products/id

and I have this in the htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

is there a solution, or is this caust by the host

thanks in advance , Richard

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) function to parse any url and seperate it into relevant parts (assuming it's a valid url).

Comment: thanks, I needed it for a webservice.
I still can't get my head around it completely

Answer (score 0):

The requested URI path and query is in [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). You can get the segments with this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$segments = explode('/', ltrim('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']));
```

Comment: but why not in the get variable url, just for clarification

Comment: You don’t need to pass the requested URL in a parameter when it’s already there.

Comment: @Gumbo, it seemed I was to quick. I can process the segments.Only the page does not display normal anymore. But I don't need the page.I only need to send xml back. Sorry

Comment: still, it should put the segments in the get variable and display the page normally I would think?

Answer (score 0):

The url passed to index.php will never include the hostname, port, or query string. (Source: [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)).

Since the rest of the url is separated by forward slashes, you could use [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) to turn it into an array.

```
$uri_segments = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
```

Note: What the array actually contains depends on where the RewriteRule occurs.  If it's in an .htaccess file or `<Directory>` block, parts of the matched block will be missing (anything before the current directory in the url).

Comment: thanks, I have it
for using REST I can now use a class for the first segment, the second for the method, the third for any more variables.
The problem above was related to a css file that did not started with a slash. Now I can go figuring the rest out.